# Select layouts based on device screens of mobile device

Tags: android, ios, html, web-applications

To prototype layouts for a mobile app, I'm going to use [Codiqa Desktop](https://codiqa.com). After that, I'm going to fine tune using an ordinary editor.

**May I somehow instruct [Codiqa](https://codiqa.com) to manage different layouts in one project?** Instruct Codiqua in such a way, that it does edits in a CSS file that belongs to the selected device size (e.g. iPhone 4 vs. iPad)?

Suppose, I'm going to target iOS and Android phones and tablets.

Do support libraries exist, which **select the adequate layout and/or adapt the layout** based on the target device's resolution?

**Do all iOS and Android devices support HTML 5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define different layouts with css media queries: [Turotrial @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

As for support on different devices, here is quick overview what you can and cannot use on specified browser: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)